# Cron invoked function looping till given time

Tags: php, cron

I am writing a task which will be ran by as a Cron Job. I want the function to check if a file has been downloaded to the server yet. The time stamp check is fine, however what is the best way to make the check loop run every 15 minutes? Could I use sleep and then check the current time stamp againsed the time stamp I want the loop to terminate (5am)?

Cheers.

Comment: Surely better to let cron handle the 15 minute intervals?

Comment: It is going to conditionally include_once() another file, this file contains the data import script: so once it has finished the download and fired the import script, it no longer needs to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what cron does.  Crontab allows you to set an interval to run a script.  It is easy to specify 15 minute intervals.  This way you won't have to worry about sleeping or error recovery or anything in your php script, just your logic.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/run-cron-command-every-15-minutes/